# Compare two columns with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have two column, say A and B. I want to compare if A exceeds column B more than 500, add 1 in new column, else 0.

My sample df:

```
A       B
13450   12000
10000   12000
5240    5000
5000    5000
60000   70000
```

Expected result:

```
A       B        C
13450   12000    1
10000   12000    0
5600    5000     1
5000    5000     0
60000   70000    0
```

Using the 'Greater Than' I can compare two column, but I can't figure out how to do this for a condition A column exceeds B more than 500.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Share what you tried, and tell us about the issue you are facing?

Comment: I didn't try yet as I can't figure out how to compare with a condition A column exceeds B more than 500.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
>>> df['C'] = (df.A - df.B).ge(500).astype(int)
>>> df
       A      B  C
0  13450  12000  1
1  10000  12000  0
2   5240   5000  0
3   5000   5000  0
4  60000  70000  0
```

You can find the difference of the column using the `-` operator, then check condition is greater than `500` using [`pandas.Series.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html#pandas-series-ge) method and finally convert it into `int` type by [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas-series-astype)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
df['c']  = np.where((( df['a']-df['b']) > 500), 1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a very simple logic just some basic comparing operation to be performed

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('pathoffile.xlsm') 
a = df['col1'].tolist()
b = df['col2'].tolist()
c=[]
for i in len(a):
  if a[i]-b[i]<500:
    c.append(0)
  else:
    c.append(1)
print(c)
```

Now write the c value into the xls file in third column into the xls file and you will get the desired result.